# Dragging a sprite in Android

Tags: android, scroll, touch-event, touchscreen

I'm simply trying to drag a sprite around using my finger.  I'm doing this by detecting the distance the finger that is touching the screen has moved by and then moving the sprite by the same amount.

This is an openGL ES 2.0 app, so my rendering and logic updating takes place on my GL Rendering thread, and obviously touch events are captured on the UI thread.

So, my setup is something like this:

**UI Thread**

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            movedByX = event.getX()-oldXPosition;
            movedByY = event.getY()-oldYPosition;

            oldXPosition = event.getX();
            oldYPosition = event.getY();
            break;

    }
```

**GL Rendering thread**

**Rendering**

```
@Override
public void render() {

    drawSprite(testSprite);  //Draws using the sprites' internal x and y coordinates

}
```

**logic update**

```
@Override
public void updateLogic() {

    testSprite.x+=movedByX;  //Update the sprite's X position
    testSprite.y+=movedByY;  //Update the sprite's Y position

}
```

**The issue**

If one drags the sprite around the screen for a while, and then stops.  The resting point of the finger *relative to the sprite* is **not** the same as it was when the finger initially went down.  Take for a example a circlar sprite like so.  The **blue circle** is the sprite and the **red dot** represents the finger/pointer.

[image]

So as you can see, it doesn't quite work as expected and I'm not sure why.

I had a similar question in previously in which I 'worked around' the problem by initially grabbing the X and Y in ACTION_MOVE (onTouchEvent/UI Thread) as I am above, but then in my updateLogic method, I make a copy of it and work out the 'moveByY' amount there before applying it to my sprite's position.

Doing this effectively solved the problem of the finger 'wandering' - *but* - it makes the movement of the sprite very choppy, therefore I can't use this solution.

I think this choppiness may be because the rendering thread sometimes runs twice without the UI thread running, therefore, even though the finger has moved, the logic is still using the version it has because onTouch hasn't been able to capture to actual most up to date finger position.  But I'm not 100% sure.

If I simply update my sprite's positionin my UI thread, (again, in ACTION_MOVE) - again, I get very choppy movement but the pointer position does remain correct).

So, I need to keep the smooth movement that I get from the method outlined at the top of the question, but I need to know why the moveBy amount is causing the sprite to wander from the finger.

**Other Notes**

I need to move the sprite using a the difference between the finger's old and current positions, and not simply draw the sprite at the finger's current position because this will eventually become part of a 'scrollable' menu system.

All of my variables are declared as 'private float volatile' and my onTouchEvent and updateLogic methods are synchronised.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if its a typo

```
@Override
public void updateLogic() {
testSprite.x+=movedByX;  //Update the sprite's X position
testSprite.x+=movedByY;  //Update the sprite's Y position
}
```

but you set testsprite.x both times

Comment: Oops yes that was a typo. Thanks. This shouldn't be a answer BTW it should be left as a comment :-)

Comment: i know - but i dont have 50 reputation... so i cant comment - which is weird

Comment: Ah OK yes, very strange rule.